# AJAX returns 2 values at onclick event

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cart

I am building a pretty simple cart script to get into ajax a bit.

My products are `<div>` elements which contain a form which looks like this:

```
<form action="add-to-card" method="post" id="frmBox">

    <input type="hidden" name="articlenumber" value="'.$row['article_number].'">
    <button onclick="formSubmit()">Add to cart</button>

</form>
```

the formSubmit() script is this:

```
function formSubmit() {
        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            url: 'add-to-cart.php',
            data: $('#frmBox').serialize(),
            success:function(response) {
                alert(response);
            }

        });
        return false;
    }
```

Inside the 'add-to-cart.php' i just start a session and use array_push to add the values to the script.

The problem: everytime i add something to my cart, it automatically adds the first product into the array.

Example: I add product 0004 -> `$_SESSION['cart']` returns this: `array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "0001" [1]=> string(4) "000" }`

Edit:

Code of add-to-cart.php

```
session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}

array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_POST['article_number']);


header("Location: shopping-cart.php");
```

Comment: can you update your answer with add-to-cart.php  codes. To check how you have implemented your add to card page

Comment: You do have a different `id` for each form, don't you?

Comment: @droopsnoot i tried with class already cause i read that id is unique, but still it makes the same mistake, with classes it just takes the last instead of the first one to add withot my influence

Comment: You have to have some way for jquery to know _which_ form it should serialise and send to your PHP code. Whether you use an id (which must be unique, so isn't suitable) or a class, there has to be some way of distinguishing which one was triggered. I'm not big on JS/JQuery, could you use `$(this)` to get the contents of the form rather than specifying `$('#frmBox')`, to indicate that it should use the form that triggered the function ?

Comment: @droopsoot when i create the same just this $(this) it still returns two, one is the one i clicked and the other one returns `NULL`